# How to connect SoftAP-mode device and send wifi info using TCP?

Tags: android, react-native, tcp, reference, access-point

I'm try to make react-native application.
 I'm looking for the way to connect SoftAP mode device, and send other wifi information(wifi_name, wifi_pw) for device can access to the wifi.
I'don't have any idea, Can someone give recommend something to refer to??

Reference doesn't need to use react-native source, just can build apk...

Comment: Did you found any solution ? @BigJ